# Is there a way to import pages via CSV in apostrophe-cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I know apostrophe-pieces-importer works for pieces, just wondered if there was a way to import pages and content via CSV. I plan to screen scrap our old site and migrate it into apostrophe-cms.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not. However it's not difficult to DIY. If you take a look in MongoDB you'll discover that a page is as simple as you would hope. Importing media as an Apostrophe attachment is the most challenging bit. If you check out the `apostrophe-legacy-import` module you'll find our code for migrating content from 0.5 to 2.x, which covers that use case and could be borrowed very profitably for your purposes.

The most important bit of going DIY on this is understanding how relationships between pages work. Every page has both a `slug` and a `path`. `slug` is what you see in the address bar, but `path` expresses the true relationship between that page and others.

The home page will have its `path` set to `/`, and its direct children might be `/about`, `/contact`, etc. Their children will be `/about/people`, `/about/services`, etc. And these will stay the same, always containing the path of the parent as a prefix, even if the slug gets edited for brevity by the end user.

In addition, each page has a `rank` property. This expresses its rank among children of the same parent, starting from `0`.

Finally, the `level` property represents the page's depth within the site. The home page is always level `0`. Technically this duplicates information you could parse from `path` but it is much more convenient when you want to quickly know the depth of a page.

In addition, all pages (and all docs in general) will have a unique `_id`, which should be a string (we recommend you use `apos.utils.generateId`, never use an automatically generated MongoDB ID). They will also have a `title`, and `tags` should at least be an array even if it is empty.

What else to include is up to you; you can inspect any doc in mongodb to see how areas are represented, and schema fields are even more straightforward.

Comment: I'm needing to import from a screen scraped CSV file since I'm sure there isn't an Umbraco 4 to apostrophe cms importer.

Comment: I understand. The technique I've described is your best approach at the moment. You could reach out to us about prioritizing a CSV page importer as an enterprise support project.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this has changed - you should now use the `apostrophe-headless` module (https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless) to be able to create content via a REST API, and then later remove the module when in production.

There are alternatives, including a CSV import for pieces but AFAICT that's just for pieces and won't work for pages and attachments, whereas apostrophe-headless seems quite comprehensive.

The only thing to watch out for is that all fields must be defined in your module's `addFields`, so where some of the tutorials suggest that you just add an area with rich text (for example) that's not enough because headless won't know that it's there - instead, use the example for `apostrophe-custom-pages` to implement `addFields`.

Manually creating database entries is hard work, and when you see the records that `apostrophe-headless` creates in comparison to manually editing you can see that a lot of work goes on under the hood - images and attachments are particularly challenging to hand code.